# How to upload NetCDF and HDF files to Geonode?

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, hdf, geonode

What is the best way to upload NetCDF and HDF files to Geonode?

Are those formats supported natively, do I have to access them programatically, or do I need to convert them to another format first?

Comment: As written your question is a little too broad and unclear, as well as having two separate questions. What have you tried so far in terms of getting a netcdf into geonode and what did or didn't work? A quick Google search found a [blog post](http://www.ggiuliani.ch/blog/?cat=6) about converting to raster in QGIS and publishing to Geonode. Your second question, how to use custom queries in geonode, would best be asked as a separate question.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment and Liam sorry for this unclear question.OK i want to upload some netcdf hdd files using geonode but i dont know if i have to do it programmatically or  if is natively supported .

Comment: I've edited your question with your comment information (you can/should do this yourself by using the edit button on the bottom left) so that it might be reopened. You may also want to search here on "geoserver netcdf", as I see a few questions that may help or have already solved the issue for you.